# Why is my python package not discovering the class for unit testing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, python-unittest, python-packaging

May be lame question for many of you smart people out there, but I am struggling with a simple python package creation.
My dir structure for package is :

```
address-book/
├── __init__.py
├── dist
│   └── book-0.1.tar.gz
├── address-book
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── person.py
│   └── person.pyc
├── address_book.egg-info
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── not-zip-safe
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── person_test.py
    └── person_test.pyc
```

The setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='address-book',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Address Book',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages('.'),
      test_suite="tests",
      zip_safe=False)
```

The SOURCES.txt:

```
setup.py
address-book/__init__.py
address-book/person.py
address_book.egg-info/PKG-INFO
address_book.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
address_book.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
address_book.egg-info/not-zip-safe
address_book.egg-info/top_level.txt
tests/__init__.py
tests/person_test.py
```

In the person_test.py I am not able to import person.py, what could be the reason?

### Solution

In case if someone struggles with the same problem, mine got fixed by not using hyphens as package name. Simple and worked!

Comment: What is the import string that you're using? Eg `from address_book.address_book import person`. Also avoid using hyphens in your package names. It may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Hevlastka yes it did work using without hyphens. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have `address-book` and `address_book.egg-info`. I think it should be `address-book.egg-info`.